# How do I reorder the rows of a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

#### Premise and what I want to achieve.

In Test2.csv, I would like to rearrange the "ID" and "Nubmer" columns in Test2.csv according to the "ID" column in Test1.csv. I would appreciate your advice. Thank you for your cooperation.
This is a simplified version of the data (more than 1000 lines).

#### The relevant source code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

input_path1 = "Test.csv"
input_path2 = "Test2.csv"
output_path = "output.csv"
df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=input_path1, encoding="utf-8")
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=input_path2, encoding="utf-8")
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')

for column_name, item in df2.iteritems():
    item = "S_" + item
    df2 = df1.reindex_like(df2)

with open(output_path, mode='w') as f:
    f.write()
```

#### Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 968, in na_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 221, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 70, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/roperator.py", line 9, in radd
    return right + left
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "narabekae.py", line 14, in <module>
    item = "S_" + item
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1048, in wrapper
    result = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 970, in na_op
    result = masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 464, in masked_arith_op
    result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/roperator.py", line 9, in radd
    return right + left
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

#### Ideal state (output.csv)

```
ID,Number
AA,2.13
BB,2.21
CC,2.09
DD,2.38
EE,2.52
```

#### Use file 1 (Test1.csv)

```
ID,Number
AA,2.1
BB,2.2
CC,2.3
DD,2.4
EE,2.5
```

#### Use file 2 (Test2.csv)

```
ID,Number
CC,2.09
EE,2.52
AA,2.13
DD,2.38
BB,2.21
```

#### Additional information (e.g., FW/tool version)

macOS 10.15.7 Python 3.7.3 Atom

Comment: Rearrange the columns? Do you mean the rows, like you say in the title? The columns already seem to be in the same order anyway. Also, the traceback seems incomplete (it doesn't mention anything about the code you actually posted).

Answer (score 0):

If both files have the same number of rows then this should produce the required output:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=input_path1, encoding="utf-8")
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=input_path2, encoding="utf-8")
(df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='ID')
    .set_index('ID')
    .drop('Number_x', axis='columns')
    .rename({'Number_y': 'Number'}, axis='columns')
    .to_csv(output_path)
)
```

Output:

```
ID,Number
AA,2.13
BB,2.21
CC,2.09
DD,2.38
EE,2.52
```